# How to convert data type (string) to type (form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form name stored in a string variable, and i want to pass this string to class which take Form Type

```
string Str = "MainForm";       // this is form name 
// I try to convert the data type string to form type like this
Form FormNm = (Form) Str ;
// there is the message appears cannot convert type 'sting'   to 'form'
TransLang.SaveControlsLanguage(FormNm);   // this is the class
```

Thank you

Comment: updated the ans little more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  Form frm = (Form)asm.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplication1.<string>");
  frm.Show();
```

add this to your code.

Answer (score 3):

```
string myType = "MyAssembly.MyType";

Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll"); // creating instance by loading from other assembly
//Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();  // for creating instance from same assembly
//Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(); // for creating instance from entry assembly
Type t = asm.GetType(myType);

Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t, null, null);
```

since it is a System.Windows.Form if u want to show the form  u can do like

```
Form frm = obj as Form; // safely typecast
if (frm != null) // kewl it is of type Form
{
    //work with your form
    fmr.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly convert a `string` to a `form`. you should create a new form and set the name of the form to the related string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can not basically. What you *can* do is define custom cast operator, which based on some logic, given specified string, creates a form. But this would be **pretty wired** solution.

Instead, simply re-architect your code and create a form based on the string provided. For example:

```
//Dictionary of the string versus Forms
Dictionary<string,Form> data = new Dictionary<string,Form> {
   { "string1", new Form1()}, //different form type are associated
   { "string2", new Form2()}  // to different string keys
    .....
}; 

public Form GetForm(string value){    
   return data [value];
}
```

Just an idea, architect what you *exactly* need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Form newForm = (Form)asm.CreateInstance("WindowsFormsApplication1.<string>");
newForm.Show();`
```